# Firing OnCheckedChanged event with ASP:RadioButton

Tags: vb.net, events, radio-button, oncheckedchanged

I have the following RadioButtons:

```
<asp:RadioButton id="rdoStandard" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="delivery" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoExpress" runat="server" GroupName="delivery" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdoNextDay" runat="server" GroupName="delivery" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
```

And in the code behind I have this:

```
 Protected Sub Check_Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles rdoStandard.CheckedChanged, rdoExpress.CheckedChanged, rdoNextDay.CheckedChanged
            RaiseEvent DeliveryOptionChanged()
        End Sub
```

I have tried the above but also tried different ways, such as a click method for each of the `RadioButtons` and I never hit the `Check_Clicked` method.

I do not want to `AutoPostBack`, and cannot see why you would want to if you were firing an event?

Its been a while since I used `VB` and WebForms, Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [`AutoPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to true if you want to trigger the event immediately, default is `false`.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="rdoStandard" AutoPostback="true" runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="delivery" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked" />
```

<sub>Note that a `RadioButton` inherits from `CheckBox`, therefor it inherits the `AutoPostback` property therefrom</sub>

**Edit**: If you want to avoid a postback, this event is also raised on the next roundtrip to the server when you don't set `AutoPostback` to true. You could for example use a submit-button, both, the Button's and also the CheckBox' click events are raised successive.

Comment: does the AutoPostback cause the whole page to refresh?

Comment: @Tyler: If you don't use ASP.NET-Ajax, yes, as every postback. Edited my answer.

Comment: So would it be possible to fire the event and prevent the postback with ASP.NET-Ajax? And could you show me how?

Comment: @Tyler: Even ASP.NET Ajax does not prevent from postback, actually it also passes the whole page-lifecycle. The only difference is that not the whole page is refreshed on the client but only parts of it(defined via UpdatePanels). So you won't see any flickering. Apart from that i would suggest to read some Ajax tutorials like this: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Comment: yeh its been a while since i did all that stuff, but guess i'm going to have to go down that road. thanks